# grid.layout doesn't like respect and compound units

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid, gtable

Using `unit.pmax` as the default comparison of widths/heights in gtable is proving harder than I'd hoped; after several hours of head scratching I've narrowed it down to this situation:

```
library(grid)

w <- list(unit(1,"null"), unit(1,"null"))
class(w) <-  c("unit.list", "unit")
h <- unit(1, "in")
gl1 <- grid.layout(1, 2, widths = w, heights = h,
                   respect = TRUE)
grid.newpage()
grid.show.layout(gl1) # fine

w2 <- w
w2[[1]] <- unit.pmax(unit(1,"null"), unit(1,"null"))
gl2 <- grid.layout(1, 2, widths = w2, heights = h,
                   respect = FALSE)
grid.newpage()
grid.show.layout(gl2)# fine

gl3 <- grid.layout(1, 2, widths = w2, heights = h,
                   respect = TRUE)
grid.newpage()
grid.show.layout(gl3)

## Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_setviewport, vp, TRUE) : 
##  non-finite location and/or size for viewport
```

so the combination of `unit.pmax(unit(1,"null"), unit(1,"null"))` and `respect = TRUE` makes grid complain. In case you're wondering, that situation would come up in ggplot2 with `facet_grid` and `theme(aspect.ratio = ...)`.

I can vaguely picture that `unit.pmax()` should simplify null units before attempting to use the `respect` parameter, but I don't really know what this all means. In practice though, it prevents me from improving gtable's cbind/rbind.

Any workaround?

*Edit:* I'm not sure how to provide a minimal example with `ggplot2`, other than installing [my fork](https://github.com/baptiste/gtable) and running

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:8, y=1:8, f=gl(2,4)), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +  
  facet_grid(f~.) + 
  theme(aspect.ratio=3)
# Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_setviewport, vp, TRUE) : 
#  non-finite location and/or size for viewport
```

so `unit.pmax()` fails in this case, while the current comparison method `compare.unit(,,pmax)` fails in other situations, such as,

```
p1 = qplot(1, 1); p2 = qplot(1,1)
cbind(ggplotGrob(p1), ggplotGrob(p2), size="max")
# Error in mmm < each : comparison of these types is not implemented
```

Comment: IIRC, unit calculation, i.e., `unit.pmax` etc, is possible only at the drawing time.

Comment: And could you show the concrete situation wherein you need the workaround?

Comment: @kohske good to see you here -- I'm working on Paul Murrell's fork of gtable as a base, trying to implement a few additional functions and fix some issues. Specifically, this problem came up with cbind/rbind; trying to use [unit.pmax instead of `compare.units(,,max)` fails](https://github.com/baptiste/gtable/blob/master/R/rbind-cbind.r#L46) for ggplots that use a combination of `facet_grid()` and `theme(aspect.ratio = ...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix by Paul Murrell in R-devel [@r65845](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/850a82c30e91feb47a0b6385adcbd82988d90413) appears to solve the problem. Unfortunately, that means the update to `gtable` will have to wait at least until the next R release (and possibly much longer, as ggplot2 dev usually takes a conservative approach about supporting older releases).

Comment: +1 Well done! I just compiled the latest R-devel, and can confirm that Paul Murrell's fix works for me too (i.e. all of the examples in your OP now work just fine).

Comment: I hear it should make it to R-patched 3.1.1

Answer (score 3):

It's not optimal, but if all else fails, you could just rewrite `unit.pmax` to make it do what you wish it did.

The following function acts just like `unit.pmax()` except that, whenever it's asked to find the maximimum of two or more unit objects, all in `"null"` units, it returns their value of the "largest" one, rather than an expression of the form `max(x,y,...)`. (See the second code block below for an example.)

```
unit.pmax2 <- 
function (...) 
{
    select.i <- function(unit, i) {
        unit[i, top = FALSE]
    }
    x <- list(...)
    numargs <- length(x)
    if (numargs == 0L) 
        stop("no arguments where at least one expected")
    maxlength <- 0L
    for (i in seq_len(numargs)) if (length(x[[i]]) > maxlength) 
        maxlength <- length(x[[i]])        
    ## result <- max(unit.list.from.list(lapply(x, select.i, 1L)))
    UL <- grid:::unit.list.from.list(lapply(x, select.i, 1L))                 ##
    result <- if(all(sapply(UL, attr, "unit")=="null")) {                     ##
                  UL[which.max(UL)]} else {max(UL)}                           ##
    if (maxlength > 1L) 
        for (i in 2L:maxlength) {
            ## result <- unit.c(result, max(unit.list.from.list(lapply(x, 
            ##             select.i, i))))
            UL <- grid:::unit.list.from.list(lapply(x, select.i, i))          ##
            temp <- if(all(sapply(UL, attr, "unit")=="null")) {               ##
                        UL[which.max(UL)]} else {max(UL)}                     ##
            result <- unit.c(result, temp)                                    ##
        }
    result
}
```

To see the difference between `unit.pmax()` and `unit.pmax2()`, compare:

```
A <- list(unit(1,"null"), unit(1,"null"), unit(1,"null"))
B <- list(unit(1,"null"), unit(4,"null"), unit(1,"null"))
C <- list(unit(1,"null"), unit(2,"null"), unit(1,"inch"))

class(A) <- class(B) <- class(C) <- c("unit.list", "unit")

unit.pmax(A, B, C)
# [1] max(1null, 1null, 1null) max(1null, 4null, 2null) max(1null, 1null, 1inch)    
unit.pmax2(A, B, C)
# [1] 1null                    4null                    max(1null, 1null, 1inch)
```

Testing it out shows that it works. (Note that you also need to replace `w2[[1]] <- ...` with `w2[1] <- ...` to avoid a complaint when `respect = TRUE`.)

```
library(grid)

w2 <- list(unit(1,"null"), unit(1,"null"))
class(w2) <-  c("unit.list", "unit")
h <- unit(1, "in")

w2[1] <- unit.pmax2(unit(1,"null"), unit(1,"null"))
## w2[[1]] <- unit.pmax(unit(1,"null"), unit(1,"null"))  ## For comparison
gl3 <- grid.layout(1, 2, widths = w2, heights = h,
                   respect = TRUE)
grid.newpage()
grid.show.layout(gl3)
```

[image]

Comment: nice work, thanks! I anticipate problems though, if we have `w2[[1]] <- unit.pmax2(unit(1,"null"), unit(2,"null"))` for example. I suspect the real solution would be to special-case the comparison of multiple null units (simply returning the max value).

Comment: @baptiste Great point. I just fixed that and changed the explanation up top and the example in the 2nd code block to reflect/highlight the change. (Knew I wouldn't get it right on the first iteration, but figured you'd be an ideal person to just bounce the idea off of!)

Comment: Excellent edit, that should work. Unfortunately using non-exported grid functions would compromise its use in a package. Maybe the best option is to file a feature request for grid itself.

Comment: @baptiste For sure. I almost suggested that earlier, as I'm guessing Dr. Murrell would be receptive to the request, or else that he would have some other good suggestion. Please let me know what you hear back from him.